# Finding Elements with Prime Power Orders in the Ring of Integers Modulo 463

Tags: group-theory, sagemath

Let $\mathbb{Z}^*_{463}$ the ring of integers modulo 463 without the $0$ element. I need to find an element of $(\mathbb{Z}^*_{463},\cdot)$ which have as order a power of a prime. For example, let 27 the order I want to find. I have never studied how to use Sage but I've just tried several efforts, for example

```
G=GF(463)
wanted_order= 27
for n in G(n):
    order = n.order()-1
    if ordine == wanted_order:
        t=1
        print("Found! ", n)
        break
if t==0:
    print("Not found")
```

Unlucky the result is always "Not found". Indeed, I've checked all the elements and it says that the order is always 462, but it's not possible.

So, I tried to change the way and I thought to find the subgroup of each element and evaluate the number of its elements with the following code.

```
G = IntegerModRing(463)
sigma = G("8")
H = G.subgroup([sigma])
H=list(H)
print(len(H))
```

However, this effort resulted in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'IntegerModRing_generic_with_category' object has no attribute 'subgroup'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I am not an expert in Sage, but I can imagine several problems. First, why do you subtract 1 from the order? Second, and this seems prettt likely, it could be you are computing the *additive* order of the elements, which is always 463 as 463 is prime. Finally, another problem could be that there do not exist elements of multiplicative order 27.

Comment: As @SomeCallMeTim says, you're getting the additive order and subtracting one from it. Use `n.multiplicative_order()` instead of `n.order()`.

Comment: Since 462 is not divisible by 27, you're not likely to find anything, though.

Comment: As others have mentioned: (1) you need to look for prime powers dividing 462 and (2) you should use multiplicative_order(n) instead. There are also some other minor issues with your code but once those were fixed I got the desired results.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Yeah, I thought that because the result was always 463, so it includes in the subgroup also the $0$ element

Comment: @FatLip Ok. I noticed that the factorization of 462 doesn't include a prime power, so I decided to change number. I have chosen $p=4159$ because its factorization is $2\cdot3^3\cdot7\cdot11$. So, I have checked if the function `n.multiplicative_order()` works and yes, it does. Despite all, I have a problem with the for statement because the argument G(n) is not correct.

Comment: @Dan_Mir I think it should just be G (no n). You then need to handle 0 somehow since it doesn't have a multiplicative order.

Comment: @FatLip I get `ArithmeticError: multiplicative order of 0 not defined since it is not a unit modulo 4159` because $0\in G$. How can I skip the 0 element?

Comment: E.g. by adding "if n!=0:" before computing the order.

Comment: I have solved the problem thanks to comments above. I can close the discussion